# Why my search box is not searching anything?

Tags: html, css, search, box

My HTML And CSS are here. I have got this code from the popular site w3schools.com. What do I have to write where?

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
input[type=text] {
width: 130px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('searchicon.png');
background-position: 10px 10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Animated search form:</p>

<form>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `<form>` tag needs to know what to search, by using a `method` and `action` attribute.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: @Lee — It's a search form, so a GET request is fine, so there is no need for a method attribute as GET is the default.

Comment: @Lee — The action attribute is also optional, if omitted it will default to the URL of the current page, which is often desirable.

Comment: You need to addup with functionality codes

Answer (score 3):

The [guide you appear to have followed](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animated_search.asp) is called "How To Create an Animated Search Form", unfortunately it is a guide that is entirely about the "Animated" page and doesn't have anything to do with Search.

The purpose of a form is not to perform a search. It is to collect data from the user and send it to a server side program.

You need to write (or find) a server side program that will perform the search for you.

Start by picking a programming language that your server supports for server side code.

Comment: @SumairAli — No, it's a massively broad task.

Answer (score 0):

As you say in comments you are using blogger. Use this form in blogger. It works

```
<form action='/search' class='search-form' method='get' role='search'>
    <input class='form-control' name='q' placeholder='search' type='text'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is just html design page. You have to write some code for searching. Like **onchange** event what you code do.

Create a javascript function and call that function on **onchange** event.

Comment: i am using blogger can you please write js code for me please